How to disable a single row of a QTableWidget header
With PySide6, is it possible to disable a specific row of the vertical header of a QTableWidget?
Currently, I am catching the signal correctly when the header row is clicked
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        self.board.verticalHeader().sectionClicked.connect(self.pick_choice)

    def pick_choice(self, row: int):
        if self.board.item(row, self.current_player).text():
            QMessageBox.critical(self, "Wrong choice", "You have made that choice already!\nPlease pick another one")
            return

but it would be much better to just disable the row in the header once it's been picked, instead of having to warn the user that row was chosen already.
I have read lots of questions and answers, and the closest thing to what I need was
tableWidget->hideRow(row)

However, I don't want to hide the row, as the user must be able to see the content of the cells of such row, but be prevented from picking it again.
Is there an equivalent that just disables the row?
Something like tableWidget->disableRow(row) ?
Please help, as I am developing my very first Qt application.
Many thanks in advance

Why can't you just ignore the click? How should the section clicking affect the program behavior and why is it necessary to always click a "different" row? It seems that your issue comes from a odd (or poor) UI logic implementation, and while your query may be valid in concept, it's probably not what you should be looking for (see XY problem).

@musicamante I am in fact at present ignoring the click, in the end. Still, I'd like to know how to let the GUI drive the allowed events, instead of doing it in the app code

Qt, as a framework, has to provide a standardized form of a complete and also efficient API. While "disabling" a whole row or column may be a reasonable need, it's not such a common need that would justify lots of changes in that API, in order to make it consistent with other aspects. Specifically, what would "disabling a row" result in? It could mean in disabling all items in it, which could complicate things (in relation to UI interaction and appearance). But you're not interested in that, since you're using a peculiar way to "select" something that is external to the view.

Shortly put, there's no way to "drive" events if not by doing it programmatically. A possible solution could be to override both mousePressEvent() and mouseReleaseEvent() of the view in order to check if the currently clicked section wasn't already the active/selected one prior mouse press. But that's difficult to achieve and probably not completely reliable. As said, it seems that your request comes from an odd logic, which may also be a bit unintuitive to the user. If you need to do some form of "please select items that xyz", then you should enter a "selection state" and »

» eventually leave it when done. Note that if you're asking all this because you cannot override the QTableWidget behavior since it's been created in Designer, then, again, you're asking the wrong question. This is totally doable either by using an event filter on the target widget (the header) and implementing a proper eventFilter() on the subclass, or by creating a QTableWidget subclass and use widget promotion with Designer. Do some research on the above, as there are hundreds of related posts, even here on SO.
